# Collibra: Best approach for multiple complex assets configuration

Tags: collibra

I have over 1000 assets. These assets sit in multiple systems, they have different names and xpaths / JSON paths in those multiple systems.

**Example:**
**Attribute name**
Country of the buyer
**Xpath in system ABC**
/parent/country
**JSON path in system DEF**
/origin/north/ country
**Type**
VARCHAR (30)
**System Z attribute name**
Buyer country

I'm looking for some help with establishing what's the best way to capture this long mapping in Collibra as separate communities for each system and then link them together?